# docker python3 deployment fail

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I deployed a docker container with this Dockerfile for my Django-rest-application:

```sh
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
COPY . /app/
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, docker doesn't install python3 on my virtual machine, instead it install python2. Is there a way to make sure the docker install the correct python?

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713233/docker-installed-python-3-5-2-instead-of-python-3-6

Comment: **docker doesn't install python3 on my virtual machine** - this is confusing. Docker doesnt install things on your VM, it installs them in the container you are running. Is this just me not understanding? Also how are you running your app in the docker container and how do you start the container?

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

Python 3 is deployed within your image instance not in your virtual machine.

#### How to check python 3 is well used in your image :

- Docker run

  ```sh
  docker run --rm python:3 /bin/bash -c "python --version && pip --version"
  # Python 3.10.0
  # pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
  ```
- Simple dockerfile

  ```
  FROM python:3

  ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

  RUN python --version
  RUN pip --version
  ```
- Output, please see both python version and pip version

  ```
  Sending build context to Docker daemon  41.47kB
  Step 1/4 : FROM python:3
  ---> 618fff2bfc18
  Step 2/4 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
  ---> Running in 421cfb4445ad
  Removing intermediate container 421cfb4445ad
  ---> acc0f2c36571
  Step 3/4 : RUN python --version
  ---> Running in 399632a39d32
  Python 3.10.0
  Removing intermediate container 399632a39d32
  ---> 3f78b14a2645
  Step 4/4 : RUN pip --version
  ---> Running in 5b541e3ff5a0
  pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
  ```

#### Your dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

- How to use it with docker run

  ```sh
  docker run <image id/name>
  ```

For more information :

- docker run :https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
- dockerfile : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the version of Python inside your image you can do:

```
$ docker run -it <image_name_or_hash> bash
```

when you are 'inside', run

```
python --version
```

Comment: (You can directly `docker run --rm image-name python --version` without stopping in the shell along the way.)